# Getting the results of my Treeset in another method of the same class

Tags: java

I've created a Treeset of a textfile that was read into my fileRead method and I want to pass the results to my fileWrite method. The two methods are in the same class. How do i retrieve the treeset results from the fileWrite method?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the treeset results as a member variable and then access that variable in the `fileWrite` method. Or, you could have the `fileRead` method return the treeset results, and then leave it up to the user to then pass the results into the `fileWrite` method.

And just to clarify, a member variable is a non-`static` (i.e. one per instance) variable declared in the class that contains your `fileRead` and `fileWrite` methods.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
 private TreesetResults results;

 public void fileRead(...) {
  // Determine results, then save them to member variable
  results = determinedResults;
 }

 public void fileWrite(...) {
  // Access results from fileRead and do something with them
  useResults( results );
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to java, can you give me examples? Thanks

Comment: The solution for getting the data worked. My format changed from horizontal to veritcal with brackets. I have tried "\n" and System.getProperty("line.separator");, to get it back, with no success. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user442471 That sounds like an unrelated question. If you've found a suitable answer for this question, please accept the answer. Then, consider asking a new question if you can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make your fileRead method return the TreeSet, store it in a variable and then pass that to the fileWrite method.

```
TreeSet ts = fileRead();
fileWrite( ts );
```